# analogue argmax for list of multidimensional arrays (PYTHON)

Tags: python, arrays, list

Is there an efficient way of finding the element that occurs most often in a list given that the element is an array of length 2?

Example:

```
l = [(1,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,0),(1,0)]
```

I would like this to return: (1,0) as that appears the most often.

Appears simple but I can't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `collections.Counter`

```
>>> import collections
>>> l = [(1,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,0),(1,0)]
>>> c = collections.Counter(l)
>>> c.most_common(1)
[((1, 0), 3)]
```

Otherwise you can use `max` with a lambda as the `key` argument

```
>>> max(l, key = lambda i: l.count(i))
(1, 0)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks very much CoryKramer! :) it says I have to wait 9 minutes before accepting as the right answer so will do that soon